# save determinate positions in pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I need store in a `uint8_t` pointer determinate positions of array.

Example:

```
uint8_t array[40] = {1,2,3,etc...}
```

`uint8_t *pointer = array[5] - [25]` . Save in pointer only positions between 5 to 25. I need in C++ language.

Thanks Community!

Comment: Please add more info. What should determinate positions of array mean?

Comment: what you're looking for is commonly called a `view` or a `span`, where you are referencing a existing block of memory without ownership. such implementations are ultimately just two pointers (beginning and end) or a pointer and size. the c++ standard library doesn't have a readily available implementation (except [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)) but they aren't difficult to implement

Comment: You need two pointers or one pointer and a length for that.

Comment: See `gsl::span` https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span

Answer (score 1):

```
// Indices for the desired range of values.
constexpr std::size_t first = 5;
constexpr std::size_t last = 15;

// Create a new array with the appropriate size.
uint8_t array2[last - first];

// Copy the data to the array.
std::copy(array + first, array + last, std::begin(array2));
```